# Does this approach positvely impact branch prediction?

Tags: c++, branch-prediction

I've been trying to make a type of callback function, and in the process I realized the one I prefer, might also change how the CPU handles branch prediction under the hood. I understand that over-optimizing is something one should avoid, especially early on, but this is an approach that suits my use very well, and having the effect of avoiding cache misses would be a neat bonus.

I don't understand CPU-architecture enough to answer this by myself however, so I'm curious if someone maybe knows if this impacts how branch prediction is handled, and if it does so in a beneficial way.

My initial solution would look like this: (mind you with larger blocks)

```
enum _myenum { t1, t2, t3 }myenum; //enumerator and switch 

switch (myenum){
case t1: 
    { /*a block*/ }
    break;
case t2: 
    { /*another block*/ }
    break;
case t3: 
    { /*yet another block*/ }
    break;
default: break;
}
```

And the solution that suits my use:

```
enum _myenum { t1, t2, t3 }myenum; //same enum
//a map of lambdas/functions
std::map<_myenum, std::function<void()>>lambda_map{ 
    { t1, [&]() {/*a block*/} },
    { t2, [&]() {/*another block*/ }},
    { t3, [&]() {/*yet another block*/ }}
}; 

lambda_map[myenum](); //to run the callback
```

Where I will run the `lambda_map[myenum]();` instead of the harder-to-track switch function.

But does the lambda-pointer map save the CPU from potential cache misses? Like as far as I can gather, not having to predict if statements or run through switch cases, but instead jumping to the specific function based on the set `myenum` variable, should accomplish that, right? Or at least influence it somehow.

I'm curious if a `lambda_map[enum]();` could be better on branch-prediction and avoiding cache misses, than a switch statement going through a list of possible cases.

Comment: Depending of enum values, `std::array` would be better than `map`.

Comment: Do you just want to change because you don't like the `switch` statement? Or have you measured and profiled to find out it's an actual bottleneck in your code? Or are you just falling into the trap of premature optimization? Write good, readable and maintainable code first of all. Then if it's not "good enough" (which often *is* good enough) measure and profile to find the bottlenecks and fix those only (with plenty of comments and documentation).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I mention in the question that Its not to optimize, but out of curiosity

Comment: Btw, You have to handle `default` differently in your second way...

Comment: @Jarod42 I do if(lambda_map.count(enum))lambda_map[enum]();

Comment: you are replacing a possible branch prediction error with a lookup on a map (or on array, as Jarod42 suggested): I'm not very expert in this field, but I assume you are slowing your program instead of improving performace

Comment: You should use `map.find` to do only one look_up.

Comment: @Charlie Using `if` together with jump table will probably be slower then `switch`. Especially with heavy `std::function` object. That being said this is possibly easier to maintain.

Comment: And compiler generally does good stuff to handling `switch` (it is not a chained if_else_if).

Comment: why do you think that the branch prediction for a switch statement will be worse than loading an array (or worse, as you suggest a map) and then calling a function that also more than likely isn't in memory?  You've removed the chance for a branch to hit, and replaced it with what seems a likely cache miss

Comment: You can use hardware performance counters (likely via some profiler as Intel Vtune or PAPI) to monitor branch prediction efficiency.

Comment: @UKMonkey I was thinking perhaps it would be easier to guess what I was planning, by well, specifying what I was planning. But you're saying I'm asking for a cache miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Where I will run the lambda_mapmyenum; instead of the harder-to-track switch function.

This is probably what is misleading you. A switch *statement* is not necessarily "harder to track" than some map-like structure. In fact, because of compiler optimization, it may very well be implemented as a jump table, that is an array of jump instructions, similar to what you imagine doing with your second solution.

In you case, using a `std::map` is pretty much guaranteed to be slower because of the indirections (and cache misses that go with them), and because it uses binary search to find a value. What you want is an array (`std::array`) of function pointers (use `std::function` or lambdas), using the enumerators as indices. In cases where an array is not feasable (because of the nature of the keys), a hashmap (`std::unordered_map`) can be used instead.

Performance-wise, there is no way to tell, without profiling, whether the array-of-functions method beats a compiler-optimized switch.

With that being said, I often find myself writing arrays or hashmaps (of functions or not) in place of switch statement due to personal preferences ranging from style (block nesting, placement, ...) to practical maintainability. Also because I dislike the structure of switch statements. Take this last part with a grain of salt: I'm sure there are people who prefer switch-like structures and despise the alternative.

Comment: I'm looking into arrays+enum for lambdapointers as we speak. Thanks for writing out an answer